Switch partition drive on dual boot
I have a dual boot with Ubuntu 22.04 and Windows 11. Each partition is on a specific drive, ubuntu is on a sata 500GB SSD and Windows is on a NVMe 1TB SSD.
The windows partition barely use 200GB of data.
I wanted to move the ubuntu partition to the NVMe drive and the windows to the SATA drive. Can I do it by just moving the partition with a bootable linux key or do I need something else to still be able to boot on them using grub ?
Thank you in advance !

It tried it and while I managed to keep my ubuntu partition working thanks to this article and a lot of grub repair, I had to remove my windows partition as it wasn't working properly anymore.
